# Draw offscreen portion of form to bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing

I have a program that's goal is to digitally fill out a paper form, the users fill out the Windows form which takes all that data and fills in textboxes placed over a full size image of the form. My goal is to have it capture that entire form with all the values placed on it and store it as an image.

The problem is the form is to large for most screens and the bottom portion of it goes off-screen so when it's captured it's missing the bottom portion. I've tried screenshotting it and am currently using the follow code to draw it directly to a bitmap with no luck.

```
 using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            bitmap.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\imagetest.jpeg");
        }
```

I'm at a point I may consider another solution to fill out the form such as capturing the remaining portion and splicing it with the top but I feel like their must be a better way about it.

Any suggestions on capturing a form that's not drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to almost screen cap the filled out form values on top of the form as an image background? (Correct me if I'm wrong). That is not the best way to go about it, what you would want to do is have the user fill out all the required fields of the form and when they hit the submit button, save all of the form values as strings.

Then you would want to load the image of the form into memory in the form of a `Bitmap` object. Then just use the `DrawString` method to draw the strings from the form at the correct x,y coordinates on the image in memory.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do, I was able to solve the issue of capping the offscreen portion using the code in my question however for some reason it doesn't capture the text on top only the image. Your suggestion should put me in the right direction, I'll look into doing that.